# Getting rid of unwanted CSS opacity in images?

Tags: css, opacity

I'm setting up my WordPress website and I'm using opacity to let the background image "shine thorough", which shows off the parallax scroll effect rather nicely. The problem is that the background image shines through on non-transparent foreground images too!

See http://csr-kommunikation.se/billig-hemsida-till-foretaget-blir-ofta-dyr-historia/

Tried editing the stylesheet (style.css) but I can't figure out how to get rid of it. The html structure is like

```
<article>
  <div>
    <p>
      <img> [the image with the problem AND text]
```

What I have tried:

- adding "opacity: 1.0;" to the img, div and article class styling, and
  only in article does it take effect. (But then I lose opacity behind
  the text too.)
- adding "z-index: 10000; !important" to the img class.
  No effect.

What I haven't tried:

- In the page source the image also has the class "wp-image-603" but I
  can't find where to edit the wp-image class since it's not in my
  theme CSS. Don't know if that might be where it can be solved.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome (36) and I have also tried viewing the page in Opera but it looks the same.  (Or "looked" I should say, now it looks like crap apparently...)

Comment: We need to see the CSS for the structure you have provided. Just using opacity on the image should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently making the entire `article` tag translucent, so anything that's inside will be translucent as well. Instead of what you're currently doing here:

```
article {
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.95;
}
```

Use:

```
article {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
}
```

This will only change the white background's opacity to `0.95`, while keeping the content as-is.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to add a line to override opacity inherited from the parent theme style.css and then it solved my problem!

`article {
  opacity: 1.0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}`